# fetching tags along with their values in a xdocument

Tags: xml, linq-to-xml

I have XML which contains two merged xml contents like

```
<input>
<tag1>
<value1>11</value1>
<value2>11</value2>
:

</tag1>
<tag2>
<abc>
</tag2>
```

Now i have to get all the contents preset inside tag1 . And need a xdocument to be returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`XDocument tag1Doc = new XDocument(XDocument.Load("input.xml").Root.Element("tag1"));` should do if you want a new document with `tag1` as the root element.